# Chimera in bacteria

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, bacteriology

Would you please define me the chimera in bacteria? Some sequences are clustered as a chimera table in metagenomics analysis, I know OTU table is used for clustering bacteria based on 16S rRNA, but I cannot find out the chimera? What is the difference between chimera and OTU table exactly?